# xpath to skip missing table images

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm scraping image urls and text from tables and I want to know how to collect nothing (or at least no url) for a cell whose image is missing. I don't want to remove any rows since I want to reproduce the table as is. Here's [an example](https://www.tuttopatenti.it/quiz-patente-b/risposte-corrette/segnaletica-orizzontale.php) of a table with missing images and the html to the right.
[image]

I'm using the following in google sheets:

```
=importxml(D1,"//div[@class='colsx immagine']/img/@src")
=importxml(D1,"//div[@class='coldx domanda']")
```

which works fine to get the image urls and text for each row if the images are all there (as on this [page](https://www.tuttopatenti.it/quiz-patente-b/risposte-corrette/segnali-di-precedenza.php)). But if any images are missing then I collect an url for the (wrong) image below in the table. I want to skip url collection if there's no img url.

I just starting to learn xpath, and I suspect I need to use the `|` or `not` to fix this, but need some help because nothing I've tried works.

Thanks

Comment: When you say you don't want to remove rows, you mean you'd like `IMPORTXML` to append empty cells when the corresponding image is not found?

Comment: @Iamblichus yes, that's it exactly. The point is to allow aligning of the elements with other table columns imported similarly, regardless of the presence or absence of table cell contents. "... to reproduce the table as is". I'm guessing there's some simple xpath command I'm not yet familiar with

Comment: I'm not sure this is the intended behaviour of `IMPORTXML` (I don't think it should provide the URL corresponding to an image below, if this URL doesn't exist for the current element). I'd suggest you to report this by selecting `Help > Report a problem` in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding another predicate. So assuming that you want to list the URLs of the `//div[@class='lista']` with an image, you can use

```
=importxml(D1,"//div[@class='lista' and div/img]/div[@class='colsx immagine']")
=importxml(D1,"//div[@class='lista' and div/img]/div[@class='coldx domanda']")
=importxml(D1,"//div[@class='lista' and div/img]/div[@class='coldx risposta active gius']")
```

and so on.
This should skip all class 'lista'  div's without an img tag and select its URLs.

Comment: I corrected the answer 180 degree. It's always better to provide a [mcve] (so that the answer can be tested).

Comment: You misinterpreted my question. I want to reproduce the table whether images are missing or not. Your answer omits all rows without images. I still want those rows, but you interpreted my answer as if I wanted to remove them. I admit that your interpretation is sensible so I've now added a new sentence "I don't want to remove any rows since I want to reproduce the table as is." But I'm finding it very hard to communicate this clearly. Thanks for the help.